# need React slider menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need suggestion for slide menu to show left to right notification panel .please suggest .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you are looking for toggle sliders on left/right. Material UI has this component in the name of 'Drawer'. Please refer the docs https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/